# How do I access user notifications via REST in YouTrack?

Tags: rest, notifications, youtrack, youtrack-api

I can't for the life of me find the documentation on how to access user notifications via the REST-API. 
Everything is activated and allowed in the admin settings, but what is the correct url to fetch them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to fetch notifications from YouTrack 2018.1+:

1. Make GET request to `<youtrack_url>/api/users/notifications?fields=id,content,metadata`. This will return notifications for a current user. To get notifications for all users at once use `all=true` request URL parameter. The latter requires admin permissions though.
2. The response contains fields `content` and `metadata` gzipped and base64 decoded, so decode them.`Content` stands for prerendered notification text, while `metadata` contains source notification data.

Each notification is stored for one hour, so you may want to fetch them often.

Comment: Thank you so much! Did you simply know this or is there actual documentation on this?

Comment: For anyone having the same problems as me: It is not only gzipped, it is also base64 encoded, so decode it before using gzdecode in PHP.

Comment: My bad, I totally forgot about base64. Will add this to the answer for further reference. As for documentation, well, there's none yet. I was told this is something YouTrack team is still working on.

Comment: Oh alright, I will wait on them then. But while we're at it, are there more than those three fields you can grab? Are _they_ documented somewhere?

Comment: I believe there're no more fields to fetch. But we can't be sure since there's no public documentation yet on them either.